# SearchView using AppCompat

Tags: android, searchview, android-5.0-lollipop

I implemented SearchView in Actionbar before using appcompat.v7
but when I want to use the SearchView with support library v7 it shows null exception

In style

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

In Java Class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My question is how to declare SearchView in onCreateOptionsMenu to be able to set query listener?

Comment: As Espen Riskedal said: "change android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass" is important too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the static methods in `MenuItemCompat` do deal with all AppCompat menu items. This was mentioned in [this blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) as the last item under 'New Integration'. Just replace your `SearchView` declaration with the following.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

Here's a link to the [MenuItemCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)) documentation.

**Edit:**
I just assumed you are using the latest version of AppCompat with the support for the new `Toolbar` widget.

Comment: You can do it with the `setOnSearchClickListener` method on the `SearchView`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html

Answer (score 23):

If you change `android:actionViewClass` to `app:actionViewClass` your existing code will continue working.