# Back button in action bar doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-toolbar

I'm trying to enable the back button in this really simple activity (that is instantiated by another activity), but I always get the null pointer exception and therefore my app crashes when I launch the activity (without the back button in the action bar the activity works great).
I tried many different solution posted in the internet, but none worked...
I'm following this guide : [Android Developer providing up navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Here the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.projectcalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <!--attività principale-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--attività infixToPostfix-->
        <activity
            android:name=".InfixToPostfixActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/infix_to_postfix"/>
        <!--attività figlia di infixToPostfix-->
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowPostfixProcedureActivity"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:label="@string/postfix_procedure"
            android:parentActivityName=".InfixToPostfixActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here the java file of the activity (ShowPostfixProcedureActivity):

```
package com.example.android.projectcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Stack;

import static java.lang.Character.isDigit;

public class ShowPostfixProcedureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String equation;
    private static int openBracket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_infix_to_postfix_jurney);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.infix_to_postfix_toolbar_procedure);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        TextView txview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postfix_jurney_text_wall);
        Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
        s = DataProcessor.ReturnProcess();
        txview.setText(s.pop());
        while (!s.empty())
        {
            if (s.peek().charAt(0) == '<')
            {
                txview.append(Html.fromHtml(s.pop()));
            }
            else
            {
                txview.append(s.pop());
            }
        }
        //Log.d("SPPA/onCreate","text = "+DataProcessor.ReturnProcess());
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_postfix_procedure, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

The XML file related to the layout (show_infix_to_postfix_jurney):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--ActionBar in alto-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/infix_to_postfix_toolbar_procedure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#42f480"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postfix_jurney_text_wall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#f2f2f2"/>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the XML file related to the Navigation bar (action_bar_postfix_procedure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



</menu>
```

Here the error message:

```
10-29 17:14:43.841 18822-18822/com.example.android.projectcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.android.projectcalculator, PID: 18822
                                                                                       Theme: themes:{}
                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.example.android.projectcalculator.ShowPostfixProcedureActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ShowPostfixProcedureActivity.java:51)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:340)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The menu XML is empty... Do you really need the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method?

Comment: You left MENU xml blank, thats why null Ponter exception occurs.

Comment: It also looks like your stacktrace and source code don't correlate. Maybe try to clean your project and stop instant run. Also you should call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369469/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-android-view-view-and

Comment: You where right, as soon as I put, ANYTHING in the menu file, it start working!
Thank you ^^

Comment: Since I want an empty bar, I don't need the `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}` method, if I get rid of it everything work great :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the line `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` is supposed to do. If you want to close the activity on the press of the back button replace it with the method call `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed()
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: *To navigate up when the user presses the app icon, you can use the NavUtils class's static method, navigateUpFromSameTask(). When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity.* - https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks. Wasn't sure if this was a users own class he was using. I've always just used on back pressed to close activities as I can set the Intent if I need to.